# 来 + verb to indicate future

Tags: grammar

What does 来 mean in the following sentence? 今天我们来讨论一个问题 I tried to translate the sentence as follows: "Today we are going to talk about a topic/problem/question". Does 来 indicate future? Is there a difference to 要 (e.g. 今天我们要...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

来 in this context focuses on **the purpose for us to come/ gather together**, 要 just **will**. 要 connotes more of the  necessity or even mandatory. 来 is more suggesting and less mandatory.

Note: Sometimes the nuance is weak in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that "来" means 'we are going to' in this scenario. To be honest, as a native Chineses speaker, I cannot tell the difference between "来” and ”要" here.

Answer (score 1):

来 means ‘come’.

- 今天我們討論一個問題 - we discuss a problem today
- 今天我們**要**討論一個問題 -  we **need to/ are going to** discuss a problem today
- 今天我們來討論一個問題 -  we  **come/  are going to** discuss a problem today